# Optimal Wifi Settings to go through 2 walls

Tags: wireless-networking

I have recently upgraded my internet speed from 50mb to 300mb, because I will have to do a lot of homeworking and it just wasn't cutting it.
Heres how my Internet setup looks like (I'm sharing it with 3 other people, so the setup cannot be changed:
[image]

On a good day I get about 80Mbit/s through to my laptop. I decided to try upgrading to a Rogue Rapture GT-AC5300.
Unfortunately, nothing really changed. I tried messing with the Wifi Settings, but the numbers stay about the same.
Are there any Settings I can tweak to increase my Wifi Speed closer to 300 or should I just return the new Router and accept the current speed?

Comment: There is no optimal setting to do this. Place the wireless router (or an extender) as reasonably closest to the wall near your workspace. I was able to rout an Ethernet cable from my main router to my upstairs office and put a Ubiquity access point in my office to provide best internet

Comment: well I guess I'll have to give the router back then

Comment: Try a better wireless router. I have a Cisco wireless router in the basement here and it give great coverage on the main floor and tolerable coverage on the second floor (which is why the Ubiquity AP)

Comment: I thought Rapture GT-AC5300. was top of the line and it barely gets 80Mbit. Not sure if I want to keep investing in a wireless solution.

Comment: You must have matching wireless-N/AC equipment to get 300 Mbps+, and have to use wider channels than the default 20mhz. What is the client machines adapter make/model?

Comment: Intel® Dualband-Wireless-AC 7265. It gets to 450 MBit close to the router